# Best way to create Best Reactjs Project Structure Folder

Tags: reactjs

Im new in react js and i learn by doing for myfirst react js project. So im foncused about "How to create best project struckture folder in react js"?, I want make my code clean and readable for my with simple struckture project but i dont know the best way in react.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are learning React, according to the official react documentation here

https://reactjs.org/docs/create-a-new-react-app.html

The best way is to use **Create React App** here

https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app

> Recommended Toolchains
>
> The React team primarily recommends these solutions:
>
> **If you’re learning React or creating a new single-page app, use Create
>   React App.**
>
> If you’re building a server-rendered website with Node.js, try
>   Next.js.
>
> If you’re building a static content-oriented website, try Gatsby.
>
> If you’re building a component library or integrating with an existing
>   codebase, try More Flexible Toolchains.

With a current installation of nodejs, that's as simple as typing a single line of either

```
npx create-react-app my-app
```

or

```
npm init react-app my-app
```

or

```
yarn create react-app my-app
```

Answer (score 1):

React has [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-structure.html) about file structures, and they mention that you can organize your files in anyway you see fit. The key take away from the docs is: **"don’t spend more than five minutes on choosing a file structure."** Simply start by keeping all files in a single folder, and as the project grows you can but them into separate folders. Just avoid too much nesting. The docs also give some suggestions as to how to organize files.

### Grouping by features or routes

For example keep all CSS, JS, and tests together

```
common/
  Avatar.js
  Avatar.css
  APIUtils.js
  APIUtils.test.js
feed/
  index.js
  Feed.js
  Feed.css
  FeedStory.js
  FeedStory.test.js
  FeedAPI.js
profile/
  index.js
  Profile.js
  ProfileHeader.js
  ProfileHeader.css
  ProfileAPI.js
```

### Grouping by file type

You can put all components in one file and all api files in another

```
api/
  APIUtils.js
  APIUtils.test.js
  ProfileAPI.js
  UserAPI.js
components/
  Avatar.js
  Avatar.css
  Feed.js
  Feed.css
  FeedStory.js
  FeedStory.test.js
  Profile.js
  ProfileHeader.js
  ProfileHeader.css
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are some of the things I do:
1. Have separate folders for each component I create for my react applications. 
For example: A folder for the navigation component, containing files such as 'Navigation.js', Navigation.css and all the files I will need for the navigation.
2. Use destructuring, it will help you minimize the use of 'this' keyword.

I hope this shed some light

Answer (score 0):

if your project is simple, just do the standard

```
src/
  actions/
  components/
  pages/
  reducers/
  App.js
  App.css
  store.js
```